# Finding the minimum value of $a+b$ if $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n}{\left(1-\frac1n\right)^n}-e^2\right)n^2=\frac{ae^2}{b}$

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

This is the question

> If
> $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n}{\left(1-\frac1n\right)^n}-e^2\right)n^2=\frac{ae^2}{b}$$
> for $a, b\in\Bbb{N}$, then find the minimum value of $a+b$.

My approach - I first plugged $1/n=h$ and changed the overall question accordingly. After that I wrote the first complex term as $e^{Ln}(x=e^{\ln x}$ property) ,then multiplied $e^2$ and divided to that term and removed $e^2$ common from the whole term. Now I am stuck. Kindly help or suggest an alternative approach. Thank you.

[1]:[stuck at this step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vOz9k.jpg)

Comment: You just need to find the limit anyway

Comment: I attempted to math edit, but I'm not sure exactly what you are saying with the e^Ln part.

Comment: @RobertTheTutor, the property by which we replace x as e^(lnx), same base logarithm property which again gives us x only.

Comment: Ultimately, you need to find out *how fast* do the sequences $(1\pm\frac1n)^n$ converge to $e^{\pm1}$? That is, can you perhaps express the $n$th term as $A+B\frac1n+C\frac1{n^2}+$ higher order terms?

Comment: Does this help? https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4159691

Comment: @Gary, got the answer, thank you very much, it was a really a wonderful one step solution.

Comment: Is there any alternate method by using the properties of limits instead of series expansion though the series gives the answer quickly, but an alternate approach would be really helpful

Comment: You also can use L'Hopital's Rule.

Comment: This limit diverges, see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing $n$ with $\frac{1}{x}$ and dividing through by $e^2$, your problem becomes
$$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{{\exp \left( {\frac{1}{x}\log \left( {\frac{{1 + x}}{{1 - x}}} \right) - 2} \right) - 1}}{{x^2 }}=\frac{a}{b}.
$$
But
\begin{align*}
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{{\exp \left( {\frac{1}{x}\log \left( {\frac{{1 + x}}{{1 - x}}} \right) - 2} \right) - 1}}{{x^2 }} &= \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{{\exp \left( {2\left( {\frac{{\tanh ^{ - 1} x}}{x} - 1} \right)} \right) - 1}}{{x^2 }}
\\ & = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{{\exp \left( {2\left( {\frac{{\tanh ^{ - 1} x}}{x} - 1} \right)} \right) - 1}}{{2\left( {\frac{{\tanh ^{ - 1} x}}{x} - 1} \right)}}\frac{2}{{x^2 }}\left( {\frac{{\tanh ^{ - 1} x}}{x} - 1} \right).
\end{align*}
I assume we know that
$$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{{\tanh ^{ - 1} x}}{x} = 1,\quad \mathop {\lim }\limits_{w \to 0} \frac{{e^w  - 1}}{w} = 1,
$$
so the limit simplifies to
$$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{2}{{x^2 }}\left( {\frac{{\tanh ^{ - 1} x}}{x} - 1} \right).
$$
This limit can be computed by using the standard Maclaurin series of the function $\tanh ^{ - 1} x$ or by L'Hôpital's rule (if you do not want to use series at all).

Comment: I deleted my answer. eing blind, there are a lot os things I use to miss. Sorry for that.